# Как сохранять данные в классе, не используя БД в mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

В стандартном шаблоне DevExtreme, есть класс Orders.cs. И есть SampleData.cs, в котором добавлен десяток атрибутов. Отличная идея, подумал я. В моем проекте очень мало данных. Но  время от времени они могут измениться. Не хочется заморачиваться с настройкой SQL Server ради 10-ка записей. Хочется хранить атрибуты в таком же виде, но с возможностью CRUD.
Увидев между делом в одном из гайдов запись такого вида, я уже было обнадежился

```
   comps.Add(new FormInputs { Id = 1, name = "name", optional = false,  placeholder = "Введите ФИО", type="dxTextBox" });
```

Думал данная конструкция добавит новую запись в класс, но это не так. Она добавляет ее лишь в переменную.

Comment: можно посмотреть в сторону SQLite | Sql Compact

Comment: @Bald, а еще, ради 10 записей стоит глянуть в сторону XML :)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите сохранить данные то просто сериализуйте объект нужного вам класса и сохраните в постоянное хранилище, а перед использованием восстановите. Можно например воспользоваться библиотекой [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```